Ignore certain pixels in image classification/segmentation models
I have a dataset consisting of aerial photo's and would like to make an image segementation/classification model on these. For the labels I use a vector dataset containing information on the location of streets, buildings, etc, but there are also unclassified area's (private land). I don't want to create a 'new' category for these area's but would like the model to ignore these pixels and base the prediction only on the classificied area's.
What would be the best way to implement this in tensorflow?
